# AWS iOS SDK Delegate Method Not Getting Called

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I am using Amazon SimpleDB for select queries, and I am trying to use the AWS `AmazonServiceRequestDelegate`, here are the delegate methods (I have conformed in .h BTW):

```
- (void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
}

- (void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    NSLog(@"recieving data");
}

- (void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"response recieved");
}

- (void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"Completed");
}
```

They all get called except `didCompleteWithResponse:`, the method that is supposed to be called when the whole operation is completed with a response. `didFailWithError:` isn't getting called either, but I don't see any reason for my operation to fail anyways.

Here is my code to create the select query:

```
        SimpleDBSelectRequest *sReq = [[SimpleDBSelectRequest alloc] initWithSelectExpression:SELECT_STRING andConsistentRead: YES];

    sReq.delegate = self;

    sReq.requestTag = FIND_FRIENDS_SDB;

    [sdbClient select: sReq];
```

Where `SELECT_STRING` and `FIND_FRIENDS_SDB` are predefined and valid to the context strings.

What is my problem here? Thanks!

Update:

Got the delegating to work. Getting an error related to my SimpleDB SELECT queries, apparently  the syntax for my SELECT expression is invalid. I get two errors, because I am doing two queries, here are the SELECT expressions for each:

> select * from trvlogue-app where Type = 'account' AND itemName() = 'me%40rohankapur.com-account'

That is looking at the 'Type' attribute and 'itemName()' and checking if they equal to something in the domain.

> select * from trvlogue-app where Email in('kate-bell%40mac.com','www.creative-consulting-inc.com','d-higgins%40mac.com','John-Appleseed%40mac.com','anna-haro%40mac.com','hank-zakroff%40mac.com')

That is checking if these strings are present in the Email attribute in the domain.

NOTE:

Fixed it, apparently when using SELECT expressions, domain names cannot have dashes. Or dashes seem to break the requests somehow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `AmazonServiceRequestDelegate`, [this blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3RYJD3PLLN161/Using-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS-Asynchronously-Part-II-AmazonRequestDelegate-Best-Prac) can be helpful. Basically, you need to:

1. Avoid using AmazonServiceRequestDelegate in a background thread.
2. Retain a strong reference to the client.
3. Retain a strong reference to the delegate.

Also, you should make sure you called `[AmazonErrorHandler shouldNotThrowExceptions]` since you didn't implement `request:didFailWithServiceException:`. Please take a look at [this blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2PZV371MJJHUG/How-Not-to-Throw-Exceptions-with-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS) for the detail.

Comment: How would I retain a strong reference to the **delegate** AKA **self**? **request:didFailWithServiceException:** is deprecated BTW.

Comment: The object that has a reference to your delegate (`self`, in this case) has to make sure the delegate is not released until the AWS operation completes. We intentionally deprecated `request:didFailWithServiceException:`, however, you need to call `[AmazonErrorHandler shouldNotThrowExceptions]` as instructed in the blog post. Otherwise, `request:didFailWithError:` won't be called.

Comment: OK, done. But **how** would I make sure the delegate is not released until the AWS operation completes?

Comment: [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) from Apple will help you understand how Cocoa’s ownership policy works.

Comment: OK, got it to work. I am getting an error: **Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.iossdk.ServiceErrorDomain error 0.)** do you know what it means?

Comment: You should investigate the contents of the `userInfo` property of the `NSError` object. They should give you more information about the error.

Comment: OK, apparently my query syntax is invalid. Ill update the question with my logged query.